# Get data from a list returned by a python function using c++ boost::python?

Tags: c++, boost-python

I have a python function returning a list of floats:

```
# Script.py
def get_double_list():
    data_list = []
    for a in range(5):
        data_list.append(float(a/10));
    return data_list
```

I want to call this from a C++ code and get the data from the list.
I wrote the following C++ code, but extracting doubles doesn't work.
What am I doing wrong?

```
#define BOOST_AUTO_LINK_NOMANGLE
#include <boost/python.hpp>
#include <iostream>

namespace bp = boost::python;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{

    Py_Initialize();
    boost::python::object main_module = boost::python::import("__main__");
    boost::python::dict main_namespace = boost::python::extract<boost::python::dict>(main_module.attr("__dict__"));

    exec_file("Script.py", main_namespace, main_namespace);

    boost::python::object global(main_module.attr("__dict__"));
    boost::python::object get_double_list = global["get_double_list"];

    if (!get_double_list.is_none())
    {
        auto py_ex_list = bp::extract<bp::list>(get_double_list());
        if (py_ex_list.check())
        {
            bp::list py_list = py_ex_list();
            Py_ssize_t list_len = bp::len(py_list);
            std::cout << "List length is: " << list_len << std::endl;
            for (Py_ssize_t i = 0; i < list_len; i++)
            {
                auto item = py_list[i];
                auto d_ex = bp::extract<double>(item);
                double d = d_ex();
                std::cout << "Double = " << d << std::endl;
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I know that it somehow fails at

```
auto d_ex = bp::extract<double>(item);
```

(tested on MS Windows 10, Boost 1.73.0, Python 3.8.5)

Answer (score 1):

if I change *data_list* to global it works

```
data_list = []

def get_double_list():
    global data_list
    for a in range(5):
        data_list.append(float(a/10));
    return data_list
```

Comment: Hmm, annoying that one has to make adaptations in the python code, but good that you found a workaround.